# Winding Number of Limaçon

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

For $z \in \mathbb{C} \backslash \gamma^*$, let $$f(z)=\int_{\gamma} \frac{dw}{w-z}.$$

I need to find the value of $f(z)$ when $\gamma(t)=(1+3\sin(t))e^{it}$, for $t \in [0,2\pi]$ (limaçon curve).

Firstly I tried to compute the integral by definition and I got nothing. Then I searched for an image of the curve and I see that if $z$ is the point marked below

[image]

Then Ind$(z)=2$, if it's in "the outter curve" it's $1$, and "out" it's $0$. How can I solve this, should I consider different positions $z$?

Comment: The value of $f$ is, as you say/suspect, an integer multiple of $2\pi i$ at each point. Do you need more than what you've already deduced? Particularly, are you asking (i) how to compute $f(z)$ as a definite integral, (ii) how to describe (analytically) the $z$ that are in the inner loop, the outer loop, or outside, or (iii) something else?

Comment: I want to describe analytically the $z$'s in the curve yes

Comment: I'd express the regions using inequalities and polar coordinates; for that you'll want to find the angles ($t$ values) where the curve crosses itself. (The crossing point is the origin, if it matters. It's shown as $(0, 2)$ or $2i$ in the plot.)